# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET on WP-login.php (Plesk 12.5)

Tags: wordpress, centos6, plesk

My server: Centos 6.5
Plesk Version: 12.5

In all wordpress installed on my PLESK, I get error "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" when performing login on wp-login.php.

This error only occur after wp-login.php submit. This occurs at random and sporadic.

how can i troubleshoot this?

Thx!.

Comment: Check domain's apache/nginx error logs.

Comment: i found this: (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: can't get data from http client, referer: http://sub.mydomain.com/wp-login.php

Comment: Is there any PHP errors around? Also you can try to switch some web site from FastCGI to Apache+PHP-FPM or Nginx+PHP-FPM on domain's PHP settings page.